# Protocols with associated type and factory pattern?

Tags: swift, generics, design-patterns, swift-protocols

My data access layer consists of a generic `Repository` protocol

```
protocol Repository {
    associatedtype T
    func getAll() -> Promise<[T]>
}
```

and its concrete implementation:

```
class FirebaseRepository<T: Model>: Repository {
    func getAll() -> Promise<[T]> {
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

Basically, `Repository` can be `RestRepository`, `FirebaseRepository`, `PlistRepositry` etc. Repository is used by the business logic:

```
/// My business logic
class ModelService<T: Repository> {
    private let repository: T

    public init(repository: T) {
        self.repository = repository
    }
}
```

The problem comes when I'm trying to apply a factory pattern to a repository. Here's what I came in first:

```
/// Returns a concrete Repository implementation
class RepositoryFactory {
    func makeRepository<T: Model>(type: T.Type) -> Repository {
        return FirebaseRepository<T>()
    }
}
```

and this definitely gets a compiler error:

```
Protocol 'Repository' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

The only viable option I came to is this:

```
func makeRepository<T: Model>(type: T.Type, U: Repository) -> U {
    return FirebaseRepository<T>() as! U
}
```

but as you understand, the force optional unwrapping is not acceptable in the production code.

How to make protocols with associated types work with factory design pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Type erasure**. Here is an example:

```
protocol CustomProtocol {
    associatedtype AssociatedType
    func foo(argument: AssociatedType)
    func bar() -> AssociatedType
}
```

If you want to use `CustomProtocol` directly, you will receive your error:

```
let array = [CustomProtocol]()
```

> Protocol 'CustomProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

So you can make the same trick, as Swift does with their sequences:

```
public struct AnyCustomProtocol<T>: CustomProtocol {
    func bar() -> T {
        fatalError("Needs implementation")
    }
    func foo(argument: T) {

    }
}

let array = [AnyCustomProtocol<Any>]() // works fine
```

**Your problem solution in this case will look somehow like this:**

```
    class Promise<T> {

    }

    protocol Model {

    }

    protocol Repository {
        associatedtype T
        func getAll() -> Promise<[T]>
    }

    class FirebaseRepository<T: Model>: AnyRepository<T> {
        override func getAll() -> Promise<[T]> {
            fatalError()
        }
    }

    class AnyRepository<T>: Repository {
        func getAll() -> Promise<[T]> {
            fatalError()
        }
    }


    class RepositoryFactory {
        func makeRepository<T: Model>(type: T.Type) -> AnyRepository<T> {
            return FirebaseRepository<T>()
        }
    }
```

__

For further reading you can check [this](https://fewlinesofcode.com/swift,/protocols/2018/11/07/type-erasure-in-swift.html) and [Official docs on Generics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. The approach you've suggested works good, though I'd expect more clear solution. `AnyRepository` has to have method stubs, which doesn't look clean. I suppose it's related to Swift's lacking of expressiveness. Abstract class sounds a better fit for solving this problem, but we don't have such in Swift yet :-/

Comment: @AndreyGordeev, yes. But this is the most "Correct" solution of your problem, IMO. [There is a proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0026-abstract-classes-and-methods.md) for abstract classes and methods in Swift. So let's just wait :)

Comment: How would you write it  so that `let array:[AnyCustomProtocol<Any>] = [AnyCustomProtocol<Foo>(),AnyCustomProtocol<Bar>()]`  works? (where Foo and Bar are structs, for example). I am getting an error: `Cannot convert value of type 'AnyCustomProtocol<Foo>' to expected element type 'AnyCustomProtocol<Any>'`